# Is my database in the elastic pool?

Tags: azure-sql-database, azure

I am trying to set up an Azure SQL Database inside of an elastic pool. I'm not sure if I did it right.  Here's my dashboard:

[image]

And here's the actual database:

[image]

What makes me wonder if the database is actually inside the elastic pool is what's circled in red in the above screenshot.

> No elastic pool

Here's the server:

[image]

And here's the elastic pool:

[image]

Another clue that the DB is not in the pool is that the pool shows no usage.

So, I'm pretty sure I did something wrong. But I can't seem to figure out HOW to put the database inside the pool.

Help!?!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like the database is not in the pool.  Go to the Elastic Pool in the portal and click on Configure Pool, and Add Databases.

[image]

Comment: Make sure you click the save/apply button after adding the databases, otherwise this will not actually take action and (unless they have updated the UI since I last did this) not warn you of the pending change when you navigate away.